# Why dpkg says 'illegal package name in specifier' when I try to remove a package?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, dpkg

Whenever I type into the terminal the command:

```
sudo dpkg -r '/home/username/Downloads/virtualbox.deb'
```

I receive the error:

```
dpkg: error: --remove needs a valid package name but '/home/username/Downloads/virtualbox.deb' is not: illegal package name in specifier '/home/username/Downloads/virtualbox.deb': must start with an alphanumeric character

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to pass a deb file to `dpkg -r`. You should specify only package names to be removed. Once you've install a deb file, information about it is included in dpkg database (`/var/lib/dpkg/`), and you can use `dpkg -r package-name` or `apt-get remove package-name`.

Try:

```
sudo dpkg -r virtualbox-4.1
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.1
```

Replace "4.1" with the actual VirtualBox version. Run `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` to check the exact package name.

Comment: OK, but this is a deb file not provided in the software centre, this is one I downloaded from the net. I ran it (your code) and it failed

Comment: It doesn't matter.  dpkg -i takes a full filename.  dpkg -r takes the package name.  For example, if you had a package called foo_bar_0.2-0ubuntu1.deb, "dpkg -i foo_bar_0.2-0ubuntu1.deb" and "dpkg -r foo_bar".

Comment: Once you've install a deb file, information about it is included in dpkg database. You should remove ANY package using `dpkg -r` or `apt-get remove`.

Comment: Oh it seems it did work earlier when I removed virtualbox when I installed it by means of the software centre so thanks I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thats irrelevant. Once you installed a package you are able to remove it using `dpkg -r`.

Comment: @BrentonHorne VirtualBox's package names includes version numbers so you have to specify it, like: `dpkg -r virtualbox-4.1`. Run `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` to check the exact package name.